# On-Premise file backup to aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup

**Use case:**  
I have one directory on-premise, I want to make a backup for it let's say at every midnight. And want to restore it if something goes wrong.

Doesn't seem a complicated task,but reading through the AWS documentation even this can be cumbersome and costly.Setting up Storage gateway locally seems unnecessarily complex for a simple task like this,setting up at EC2 costly also.

**What I have done:** 
Reading through this + some other blog posts: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Welcome.html 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/WhatIsStorageGateway.html

**What I have found:**

***1.Setting up file gateway (locally or as an EC2 instance):***  
It just mount the files to an S3. And that's it.So my on-premise App will constantly write to this S3.The documentation doesn't mention anything about scheduled backup and recovery.

***2.Setting up volume gateway:*** 
Here I can make a scheduled synchronization/backup to the a S3 ,but using a whole volume for it would be a big overhead.

***3.Standalone S3:***  
Just using a bare S3 and copy my backup there by AWS API/SDK with a manually made scheduled job.

**Solutions:**

- Using point 1 from above, enable versioning and the versions of the files will serve as a recovery point.
- Using point 3

I think I am looking for a mix of file-volume gateway: Working on file level and make an asynchronus scheduled snapshot for them.
How this should be handled? Isn't there a really easy way which will just send a backup of a directory to the AWS?

Comment: This [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/aws-reinvent-recap-modernize-your-on-premises-backup-strategy-with-aws/) from aws has some other options including the one you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to backup a directory to Amazon S3 would be:

- Install the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)
- Provide credentials via the `aws configure` command
- When required run the `aws s3 sync` command

For example

```
aws s3 sync folder1 s3://bucketname/folder1/
```

This will copy any files from the source to the destination. It will only copy files that have been added or changed since a previous sync.

Documentation: [sync — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

If you want to be more fancy and keep multiple backups, you could copy to a different target directory, or create a zip file first and upload the zip file, or even use a backup program like [Cloudberry Backup](https://www.msp360.com/backup.aspx) that knows how to use S3 and can do traditional-style backups.